# Link a button to Table in MATLAB GUI

Tags: database, matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to link a button in a GUI interface I have created to display results in a table that is extracted from a database using a simple SELECT statement. Problem is, I can't seem to figure out how to link the button with the Table function.

At the moment I have it written such a way that it runs separate functions and opens up separate GUI windows, but I'm trying to minimize the number of windows the program opens.

**Code: Button function**

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

I manage to link the button to a Callback function (eg. `dbExtract`) I had built via the `GUI Builder -> Inspector`. That function creates another window to display the results from the database. Code and Picture below:

**Code:**

```
function conn = dbExtract()

%# add class path (if not in the class path)
    p = 'C:\FatherSon\ojdbc6.jar';
    if ~any(ismember(javaclasspath,p))
        javaaddpath(p)
    end

conn = database('xxx','xxx','xxxxxxx123','oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver','jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.10.10.10:7001/xxx');
check_connection = isconnection(conn)
sample = exec(conn,'SELECT * FROM xxx.TABLE1');
sample2 = fetch(sample);


% Table Figure plotted when data is retrieved from the database from the query above   
f = figure('Position',[200 200 1300 500]); % size of the figure object
dat = dyn_conformer.Data;
set(f,'name','Father & Son War Room','numbertitle','off') %renames the Title Figure
cnames = {'Title1','Title2','Title3'};
rnames = {'1','2','3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20','21', '22', '23', '24', '25'};
t = uitable('Parent',f,'Data',dat,'ColumnName',cnames,... 
            'RowName',rnames,'Position',[10 100 1150 370]);
```

**Picture:**
[image]

**Question:**
How do I link the button to display those results in a single window, shown in the picture below(**The Idea**)? Bottom line, I want to be able to display the results and have a button function in the same window such as below:

**The Idea:**

[image]

There's no Callback function field for when I created the Table via the `GUI builder-> Inspector`

I would appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a new figure in dbExtract(), try using gobf (get callback figure) to get a handle to the original figure/window.  Then use the find() function to find your uitable in that figure. Once you get the handle to the original uitable you can set its data.  If you don't have a uitable yet, then create one and set the parent to be the gcbf.